# Auto close Edge browser in Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webautomation

I have been trying to run selenium script. Code runs well but the browser(Edge) gets close  automatically.

Below is the error I am getting.

```
\[19796:19404:0905/212543.583:ERROR:fallback_task_provider.cc(124)\] Every renderer should have at least one task provided by a primary task
provider. If a "Renderer" fallback task is shown, it is a bug. If you have repro steps, please file a new bug and tag it as a dependency of crbug.com/739782.
\[19796:19404:0905/212549.269:ERROR:fallback_task_provider.cc(124)\] Every renderer should have at least one task provided by a primary task
provider. If a "Renderer" fallback task is shown, it is a bug. If you have repro steps, please file a new bug and tag it as a dependency of crbug.com/739782.
```

What should I do?

Code I am running:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

Browser=webdriver.Edge()

Browser.get("test.site")


Browser.maximize_window()

my_team=Browser.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT,'My Team').click()

time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: Can you post some part of the code?

Comment: The error message you shared does not pertain to core selenium. Seems like it's a web driver issue. Can you try upgrading your web driver version? Also, make sure your browser has no pending updates.

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem, Selenium is for automated testing, so it _should_ close the browser when it's finished running the test.

Comment: Unless you ask it to close the browser , it should not close it.